# Errors in hardhat.config.ts configuration file

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I'm following [this](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-deploy-a-smart-contract-to-the-sepolia-testnet) Alchemy tutorial on how to deploy a smart contract on the Sepolia testnet. When I try to compile my smart contract, I get these errors:

```
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

  * Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.sepolia.url - Expected a value of type string.
  * Invalid account: #0 for network: sepolia - private key too short, expected 32 bytes
```

Here is my hardhat.config.ts file

```js
require("dotenv").config();
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");

const { API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.7.3",
  defaultNetwork: "sepolia",
  networks: {
    hardhat: {},
    sepolia: {
      url: API_URL,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```

I've included my private key and the api_url in a `.env` file
I'm not sure where the invalid errors are coming from

Comment: can you console those ` API_URL, PRIVATE_KEY` see what u get?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue. Fix for me was to not use the entire api_url from .env file.

Use the entire string directly. 
If you want to, then include only the API_KEY in your .env file and use interpolation for the the entire url. 
The code should look like:

```
const { API_KEY, PRIVATE_KEY } = process.env;

...
sepolia: {
  url: `https://xxxxxxx/${API_KEY}`,
  accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `API_URL` with your Sepolia RPC, you can do that by just hardcoding it like `"https://xxx.xx/xxx"` or just using an env variable `${API_URL}`. Please make sure that your file is receiving the env variables correctly.